# installshield script check if we are uninstalling

Tags: installshield-2010

I am looking for a way I can pass to my installscript check if I application is uninstalling.

I tried this:

```
if (REMOVE) then
  MessageBox("uninstalling!", INFORMATION);
  return 0;
endif;
```

but it triggers even if I am installing :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't do what you want because [REMOVE](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/robo/projects/installshield16langref/LangrefREMOVE.htm) is a constant so the condition is always true. Try using [REMOVEALLMODE](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/robo/projects/installshield17langref/removeallmode.htm) instead, or look at [OnMaintUIBefore](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/robo/projects/installshield16langref/langrefonmaintuibefore.htm) to override the selection up front.